# Dropdownlist selected item text always returning the first item text

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

i am using this code to fill dropdownlist from database.

```
public void fillcountry()
{
    BL obj = new BL();
    DataSet ds = obj.dss("select * from Country  ");
    drplistcountry.DataSource = ds;
    drplistcountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
    drplistcountry.DataValueField = "CountryId";
    drplistcountry.DataBind();
    drplistcountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}
```

i am Using this fillcountry() in page load() event. 
and Rerutning selecteditm.text on Button Click event

drplistcountry is always showing First index text , How to solve it?

Comment: Where  you calling `fillcountry()` method?

Comment: On Page Load () event

Comment: You must have `ViewState` enabled in aspx page directives and for the controls.

Comment: Are you doing this every time in PageLoad, or are you checking to make sure IsPostback is false i.e. it's the first time the page is loading, and not a postback ?

Comment: in PageLoad event i am using other code with if ((Page.IsPostBack)) . i want to use this return value on button click .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4._Default" 
EnableViewState="true" %>
```

For Dropdownlist Control 
set **EnableViewState** property to true.

In .aspx.cs page:

In PageLoad event check for following:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{ 
    fillcountry();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

And you shoud call this function only once.

```
 public void fillcountry()
    {
        BL obj = new BL();
        DataSet ds = obj.dss("select * from Country  ");
        drplistcountry.DataSource = ds;
        drplistcountry.DataTextField = "CountryName";
        drplistcountry.DataValueField = "CountryId";
        drplistcountry.DataBind();
        drplistcountry.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
        drplistcountry.SelectedIndex = drplistcountry.Items.IndexOf(drplistcountry.Items.FindByText("--Select--"));
    }
```

Comment: Dear sir , I Edit the question. when i am using selecteditem.text is always returing first value

Answer (score 0):

An easy way
You can use repeater to make select in html code like this

```
<select id="ddlAlbum" class="form-control" name="Cat">
        <asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server">

            <ItemTemplate>

            <option  value='<%#Eval("CatID") %>'>
                <%#Eval("Title") %>
            </option>
                </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:Repeater>
        </select>
```

for get data from data base use ado.net

```
 public void fillAlbum()
    {
        SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=person;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter myadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select CatID,Title  from Category", myconnection);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        myadapter.Fill(dt);
        rpt.DataSource = dt;
        rpt.DataBind();



    }
```

and for get selected value.
the select element name is ("cat") So

```
string cat = Request.Form["Cat"];
```

and store to db simply

```
  SqlConnection myconnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=person;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("insert into Picture(Title,Pic,CatID) values(@pname,@pic,@cat)", myconnection);

        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pname", txtname.Text.Trim());
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pic", path);
        string cat = Request.Form["Cat"];
        mycommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("cat", cat.ToString());


        myconnection.Open();
        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myconnection.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Its is very simple but very difficult to find out, check your value `Datavaluefield` of all the items should not be blank or null.

Means:

```
ddl_Name.DataTextField = "NAME";
ddl_Name.DataValueField = "Roll";
```

if value is blank means you cannot will get the first items only.

Answer (score 0):

DropdownList selected Item Text value will  work like this.

```
String value="India";
drplist.SelectedIndex = drplist.Items.IndexOf(drplist.Items.FindByText(value));
```

Answer (score -2):

I was also facing same issue but in my case dropdown value was same for all items, which was causing issue.
So, make sure you are binding dropdown list correctly.

:)