# C# DropDownList listing number value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist that fills like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.pelischool";
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        DropDownList1.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["schoolName"].ToString();
                        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

Now I want to read the listing number of the selected item(in order to place it in a query).
So, while my dropdownlist has values like "Oxford University", "MIT University", "Simon Fraser University" etc, I want clicking an item from the list, store the value of this item in the list. To be more specific, if clicking the first item, then
int number = 1. if clicking the second item, then
int number = 2.

Is it possible to be done with something like:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedItem.????;
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: you must have some value against each schoolName in database. Bind those values in DropDownList1.DataValueField.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't `bind` item's value to `dropdownlist`, so you need to bind it.

like this

```
DropDownList1.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["Column name that contain the value of Item"].ToString();
```

and then you can use to get it's value like as follow

```
string item_value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Already did that but for a reason I am getting always the id of the first item. It is always 1 no matter what item I choose

Comment: Please show your code that you use to get the Item's Value

Comment: `
                        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        DropDownList1.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["schoolName"].ToString();
                        DropDownList1.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["schoolID"].ToString();
                        DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                        DropDownList1.DataBind();`

Comment: I have this code in the Page_Load funciton, so maybe this is the reason for being always 1. Where else can I place this code?

Comment: I found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052739/dropdownlist-selected-item-text-always-returning-the-first-item-text

Comment: There is another way to do this you can use dropdownlist's SelectedIndexChanged event

Answer (score 2):

If you want selected Value then use

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue
```

and if you want selected item then use

```
DropDownList1.SelectedItem
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from dbo.pelischool";
                            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                            da.Fill(ds);
                            DropDownList1.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["schoolName"].ToString();
                            DropDownList1.DataValueField = ds.Tables[0].Columns["SomeValueColumn or id column"];
                            DropDownList1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                            DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

and then you can use...

```
string id = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Try this.

```
 cmd.CommandText = "select id,schoolName from dbo.pelischool";
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 da.Fill(dt );
 if (dt != null)
        {
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                ddlPosition.DataSource = dt;
                ddlPosition.DataTextField = "schoolName";
                ddlPosition.DataValueField = "Id";
                ddlPosition.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This seems to be ok BUT for some reason(weird) always stores the first id. Even if I choose the second or third option of the dropdown, it stores the id of first

Comment: I have updated my answer. Kindly try this. I hope it will help you

Comment: also please share your pelischool table values. So that it would be more easy to solve your problem brother.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Nitin Kumar answer, selected item text can be obtained by:

```
var selectedText = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
```

Selected Value

```
var selectedValue = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
```