# Not able to get the dropdown list selected value on button click in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have written a simple asp.net c# code for getting the value of dropdownlist. But even after selecting some values I am always getting value as `"--Select Vendor--"`

Here is the code.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlVendorUploadData" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        <label>Vendor Name</label>
```

And code behind.

```
protected void btnUploadData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strUserRole = ddlVendorUploadData.SelectedItem.Value;
        }
   }
```

And button click code is

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUploadData" runat="server" class="btn btn-danger button" Text="Submit"
                                            OnClick="btnUploadData_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateDropdownlist();" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dropdownlist selected item text always returning the first item text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052739/dropdownlist-selected-item-text-always-returning-the-first-item-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code to fill the drop list. But, MOST often this occurs due to you re-loading the drop down list.

Always, but ALWAYS put your FIRST forms load code in the IsPostBack = false.

Any post back, any button click will ALWAYS run the page load event again, and does so EACH time.

I really wish that a separate event called FirstPageLoad existed.

So, assuming this markup:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="164px"
            DataValueField="ID"
            DataTextField="HotelName" >
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <asp:Button ID="cmdTest" runat="server" Text="Test drop select value" OnClick="cmdTest_Click" 
            style="margin-left:35px"/>
```

Note in above, we have TWO values. The first column is the hidden pk "ID" of the hotels table. And then we have the "display" value of HotelName.

So, MAKE SURE that you ONLY load up the data source for above ONE time. If you reload each time, then even on button click, the page load event fires, and your code re-loads the drop down, and you LOSE your selection when you re-load.

So, the code on page load should look like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadCombo();
    }

    void LoadCombo()
    {
        string strSQL = 
            @"SELECT ID, HotelName FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";
        DropDownList1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));
    }
```

Note the VERY important test/check for `IsPostBack`. Since page load runs on EVERY post-back (any button click for example), then we need a REAL first page load in which we load up controls, grids and do our REAL page load work and setup.

So, use the `IsPostBack` test.

The MyRst is just a handy helper routine that returns a data table - I use it over and over throughout my application.

That code is this:

```
    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }

        return rstData;
    }
```

And thus when we run, we get this:

[image]

So, after select, then we have this for the test button code:

```
    protected void cmdTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("Text property = " + DropDownList1.Text);

        // best to use this MUCH LESS confusing

        Debug.Print("Value property = " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
        Debug.Print("Text property = " + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    }
```

I like to use SelectedItem ALWAYS , and then get the Text value (display) or the hidden Value property (ID). Note that if your drop does NOT have two values? Then I suggest setting DataValue and DataText both to the one column name.

Output:

[image]

Note HOW the text property actually returns the "value" setting. You can also set the drop with

```
DropDownList1.Text = "16"
```

and it will jump to, and display the text value

So, OFTEN we need to select a part or say hotel as per above, but we want to get/have/use/work with the PK or hidden column.

So, keep in mind the 2 column ability of the drop down.

And keep in mind the page load event - you need to place your combo load up code in the `IsPostBack = false` stub else you re-load the drop down EACH time on EACH post back (such as each button click).

And as noted, to avoid confusing, I always use the `SelectedItem.Text`, or `SelectedItem.Value`, and that reduces a boatload of confusion here.

Comment: When I wrote the logic inside `!IsPostback` then it worked

Comment: Great!!! - so just keep in mind the post back issue. I had code for years that was re-loading grids or drop downs - and when you re-load these data bound controls, they lose their settings (such as which drop down you select).

Answer (score 0):

This would be easier to answer if we could see the code that generates the dropdown data. But, as far as I can see, there could be three possible issues:

1. Are you, by any chance, mixing `SelectItem.Value` and `SelectedItem.Text`, considering that a dropdown item has a `Text=""` and a `Value=""` property?
2. Could it help setting the `DataValueField` property  of the dropdown list to `"Value"` (i.e., `.DataValueField = "Value";`)—again assuming that it's the `Value` property data that you want.
3. My last idea could be that it is the dropdown's `ViewState` that is not setup properly. It can cause update problems if the viewstate is false.

Hope any of these suggestions help solve you problem.

Comment: In near all of these cases when the user states that selection is lost, and it reverts back to the original default value (such as "please select", then in 9 out of 10 cases? It due to the person re-load the grid or dropdown list EACH time. See my post - we get posts on SO near every other day due to code in on-load firing every time. Quite much next to impossible to build a working web form page if one does not follow the above rule and suggesting to have all the setup and loading of controls run ONE time inside of the !IsPostBack code stub. If one re-loads controls, you lose selection.